# Как динамично определять class_name для связи has_many, используя одинаковые таблицы разных engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Здравствуйте, подскажите как определить связь, в зависимости от атрибута модели?
У модели User есть атрибут pay_currency, который может быть 'real' или 'bitcoin'. Есть 2 engines(Tbitcoin, Tstripe) у каждого из которых есть одинаковая таблица payment.

Необходимо найти способ, как создавая payment от юзера, направлять в нужный engine автоматически.

```
# Пример создания payments
User.create(pay_currency: 'real').payments.create # => Tstripe::Payments
```

Примерный код, для задумки

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :payments, ~> { where "pay_currency = 'real'" } , class_name: Tstripe::Payment, foreign_key: :uid
  has_many :payments, ~> { where "pay_currency = 'bitcoin'" } ,class_name: Tbitcoin::Payment, foreign_key: :uid
end
```

В какое направление думать для реализации такой динамики?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, сделайте этим ассоциациям разные имена, а то они наложатся друг на друга и будет знатный ба-бах:

```
has_many :stripe_payments, class_name: Tstripe::Payment,
                           foreign_key: :uid
has_many :bitcoin_payments, class_name: Tbitcoin::Payment,
                            foreign_key: :uid
```

А потом просто сделайте выбор одной из двух ассоциаций. Есть целая куча способов.

---

Можно сделать в `User` метод, принимающий способ оплаты и возвращающий одну из двух ассоциаций (надо ловить случаи, когда получен несуществующий способ).

Можно сделать "создавалку платежей", одним из параметров которой является способ оплаты, и она внутри будет выбирать ассоциацию.

Можно просто разместить их в разных контроллерах и ссылаться не на "общие" `payments`, а только на конкретные.

Выбирайте любой.

Comment: Имхо второй способ предпочтительнее. В случае первого много неаккуратного кода, и поддерживать сложнее.

Comment: @anoam я б скорее выбрал третий. Выбор платёжного движка в данном случае отгружается на какой-то отфонарный параметр, этим параметром вполне мог бы быть контроллер. А заDRYить наследованием, если нужно.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, мощь ROR разработки это решение одной проблемы тысячами способов)), 
для решения я выбрал 1 способ(небольшим изменением), получилось, что то типа эмуляции has_many, который распределял из условия какой енджин использовать). 
Еcли кому то понадобится вот [пример реализации](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36473095/how-to-implement-dynamic-class-name-for-the-association-has-many-for-the-same-t)